# Keep only one viminfo file and disable others

Tags: vim

As far as I can tell, the `$HOME/.viminfo` file is used to record the state of vim.

But I found there are lots of viminfo files in my home path. For example:

- `.viminfp.tmp`
- `.viminfq.tmp`
- …

Can I stop this behavior of Vim and keep only one viminfo file?

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed that could be causing this? Try disabling them and deleting the existing files and see if you still have the problem. Or maybe something generated those files just once, and it won’t happen again. Additionally, what is the output of `:set viminfo?`? For me it is the default, `'100,<50,s10,h`, and I don’t have this problem. See also the documentation for [`viminfo-file-name`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#viminfo-file-name) and [`'viminfo'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27viminfo%27).

Comment: It's strange that the problem disappeared after I reintalled all my plugins. Thanks